# How to add UIButton as bottomView to UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have a UIView class, and in xib also I have a MainView which is a UIView. I want to add UIButton as bottomView to the View.I need to give bottom space 16 between MainView and bottomView. How do I do it?

```
 self.bottomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.MainView.bounds.size.height +30, self.MainView.bounds.size.width, 40.0)];
    [self.bottomView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
self.selectBtn= [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[self.selectBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,100,40)];
[self.selectBtn setTitle:@"Select" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.selectBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(selectButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.bottomView addSubview:self.selectBtn];
    [self addSubview:self.bottomView];
```

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iynmb.png)

[Output from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XZpP.png)

Comment: google iOS Autolayout Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Please find you have added button on this frame

```
 self.bottomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.MainView.bounds.size.height +30, self.MainView.bounds.size.width, 40.0)];
```

Here you have made the y as height + 30 so it is not visible to the view.

You should use this.

```
 self.bottomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.MainView.bounds.size.height - 40, self.MainView.bounds.size.width, 40.0)];
```

Also if you want 16 pixel gap you should the view above it with the same approach.

Please let me know if you need any more help